# Why does executeUnique return forwardQueryResult in DataNucleus?

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I have been trying to learn DataNucleus and JDO and found that the following expression, where pm is a `PersistenceManager`

```
pm.newQuery(A.class)
  .filter("this.id==:id")
  .setParameters(id)
  .executeUnique();
```

returns an instance of ForwardQueryResult, which is what is returned by execute methods that return multiple results. However, the signature and description of `executeUnique` indicates that it should return an instance of the class passed to `newQuery`. Why is it returning a ForwardQueryResult? Note that the compile-time deduced return type is `A`, but assigning the expression to a variable of class `A` results in a `ClassCastException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a bug, since the whole point of `executeUnique` is to return the candidate/result without having to extract it from a List (which is what that return type you see is). Maybe it is already fixed in their current codebase (and nightly builds), otherwise report it.

As a workaround, just call `setUnique()` (the old API way of doing it) on the query?

Comment: A fix for this was committed a few days ago. It should work using nightly builds now and is slated for the next release.